# Shifting letters in a String Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program that takes a string and shifts the letters int it by 3 positions.

Example:
Input "AGZ"
Output:"DKC"

I've tried looking at oracles String document about this but I couldn't find anything that I could use. Any tips?

Comment: Probably you have to convert the String to a char[] array, increment the char values, then convert back to String.

Comment: Hello `Caesar cipher`!

Answer (score 1):

All chars correspond to an int value based on ASCII, so you can do something like this:

```
String input = "AGZ";
String output = "";

for (char c : input.toCharArray())
    output += (char) (c + 3);
```

Note that this doesn't wrap the Z around to a C, but I wouldn't want to take all the fun from ya.

Comment: That's kind of inefficient, since you create a new output String on every iteration.

Comment: And if you're gonna do it that way no need for the toCharArray -- just use charAt.

Comment: It depends on the usage whether or not this is too slow. You can easily adapt this method to use a StringBuilder instead. If you don't care about crazy speed or memory usage, then I would say this is the best solution.

Comment: Why would I use a for-loop over a for-each-loop?

Comment: But still, there's zero need to create the char array to do it this way.  Unless you just like to exercise the garbage collector.

Comment: So you want this?:

for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
    output += (char) (input.charAt(i) + 3);